# Override Payload Exception of Laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption, exception, laravel-5.5

I am getting an exception of **payload is invalid** when editing the encrypted ID as manually.

I need to make as a json response for this exception like

```
   ['status=>400,'message'=>'The Payload is invalid']
```

When working with API's I am using the encrypted form of ID and I getting the HTML type exception for **Payload is invalid**. I wan to to change it to the json format for avoiding type issue in Mobile team.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to app/Exceptions/Handler.php. In render method.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException) {

        return response()->json([
           'message' => 'The Payload is invalid'
        ], 400);

    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```